# Is this graph Hamiltonian?

Tags: graphs, induction, hamiltonian-path

My case is a *directed* graph with $n$ nodes with $(n-1)^2+1$ edges. I have done the following till now.

We know that the maximum number of edges for a directed graph $K_n$ on $n$ nodes is $n(n-1)$ edges. The graph in my problem statement is $G(V,E)$ with $|V| = n$ and $|E|$ = $(n-1)^2+1$.

Now, $n(n-1) - ((n-1)^2 + 1) = n-2$, so any such graph can be obtained from $K_n$ by deleting exactly $n-2$ edges from $K_n$.

> Is my approach correct till now? How can I apply induction to prove the graph is Hamiltonian? I'm new to graph theory and inductions. As such, a comprehensive simple explanation would be much appreciated.
>
> If not induction, is there any other way to prove this?

Comment: There are some inconsistencies in your post, like confusing edges and nodes, and uneeded repetitions. Could you please correct them?

Comment: I highly recommend reading [Jeff Erickson's notes on induction](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/notes/98-induction.pdf). Yes, it's 30 pages, but induction is a key skill and I haven't seen a friendlier introduction.

Comment: This site is not for time-sensitive questions.

Comment: I do not understand this bound. If I omit all $n-1$ outgoing edges from one of the nodes of $K_n$ then the graph no longer is Hamiltonian (if we expect a cycle in that definition).

Comment: @HendrikJan So, at most $n-2$ edges can be omitted. That is the bound given in the question.

Comment: @AmalSailendran, please check my answer.

Comment: @JohnL. Right. $n-2 <n-1$, I should have noted that. (Insert blushing face icon)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4164687/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/141068/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complete digraph of $n$ nodes, $K_n$ has $n(n-1)$ edges. Describe a digraph of $n$ nodes with $n(n-1)-\delta$ edges as a digraph "with $\delta$ edges removed".

#### A proof by induction

The following is an outline to prove by induction that every digraph of $n$ nodes with $n-2$ edges removed contains a Hamiltonian cycle.

The base case, when $n=2$ or $n=3$ is obviously correct.

Suppose $n\gt3$. Let $G$ be such a graph. There are two cases.

- There is one node with exactly one edge from it or to it removed.
  Let that node be $u$. By induction hypothesis, there is one Hamiltonian cycle for the induced subgraph of the remaining nodes. Verify that cycle can be modified to pass $u$ as well, hence becoming a Hamiltonian cycle of $G$.
- Otherwise, for each node, either no edge from it or to it are removed, or at least two edges from it or to it are removed.
  Let $v$ be a node of the former kind and $w$ be a node of the latter kind.  Let $G'$ be the induced subgraph of the remaining $n-2$ nodes. Since $2(n-2)\gt n-2$ and there are $2(n-2)$ possible edges between $w$ and a node in $G'$, there must be one edge of $G'$ that is between $w$ and some node of $G'$. By induction hypothesis, $G'$ contains a Hamiltonian cycle. Verify $C$ can be modified to include that edge as well as pass $v$, becoming a Hamiltonian cycle of $G$.

#### Explanation of Yuval's neat answer

Consider **all (directed) Hamiltonian cycles in $K_n$**. What is the total number of edges in them, with duplicity counted?

- Let $f$ be the number of all Hamiltonian cycles.  Since each cycle contains $n$ edges, that total number is $nf$.
- The number of times an edge appearing in those cycles is the same for each edge, thanks to symmetry. Denote it by $p$. Since there are $n(n-1)$ distinct edges, that total number is $n(n-1)p$.

We have,
$$ nf = n(n-1)p,\ \ \text{ i.e., }\ \ f= (n-1)p $$

Let us remove edges from $K_n$ so as to obtain the given graph $G$. Since removing an edge affects only Hamiltonian cycles in which that edge appears, removing $n-2$ edges will affect at most $(n-2)p$ Hamiltonian cycles. Since $f=(n-1)p > (n-2)p$, at least one Hamiltonian cycle will not be affected after removing $n-2$ edges. That is, there is at least one Hamiltonian cycle in $G$. $\quad\checkmark$

Stating the explanation in terms of probability and expectation, we shall obtain Yuval's answer.

---

The only facts about Hamiltonian cycle used in this proof are that it has $n$ edges and that the concept is symmetric to each edge. We have, in fact, proved the following remarkable proposition.

*Given $n\ge2$, digraph $G$ of $n$ nodes with $n-2$ edges removed and digraph $D$ of $n$ nodes with $n$ edges, $G$ must contain a subgraph that is isomorphic to $D$.*

Comment: This is great! Simple and comprehensive. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you choose a Hamiltonian cycle at random, the expected number of edges missing is strictly less than $1$.

Comment: $\quad$Neat!$\quad$

Comment: That's a completely different method, using elementary probability theory.